# Running a python file other than views.py in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am running a django project and I want to divide up my python code into separate files. At the moment I am running my functions from `views.py`. In my `views.py` I have a `plot` function. I have taken this plotting code and I have created python file called `plotting.py` which has this `plot` function in it. this plotting file lives in the same folder as my `views.py`

My problem is accessing this `plotting.py` file. I am trying to access it through from the `urls.py` by `path('plot', plotting.plot),`. it is not working. Or do I have to link back to a function in views.py`and from tat function go to`plotting.py`?

Comment: It does not matter where your views are defined, `views.py` is just a convention. What do you mean when you say it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this plot function a view where you are returning a response to the client or is this a helper function that you are trying to call from within a view? If it isn't a view, I would recommend adding `from .plotting import plot` to the top of your views.py file

Comment: `from plotting import plot` is saying that i have an unresolved reference. i also tried `from plotting.py import` but the same issue

Comment: That is my fault, what if you try `from .plotting import plot`? If it is in the same directory as views.py you should use a relative import. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports

Answer (score 1):

`urls.py` should only import views and specify which URL should each view handle.
Example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#example

Since `plot` is a function (that probably is plotting something), this needs to go to the view, since it's the view that performs endpoint logic. So you need to import `plot` in the `views` file.

PS: `path('plot', plotting.plot)` would only work if `plotting.plot` was a view, but you mentioned it's just a function.

Answer (score 0):

should you not do `from plotting.py import plot` and then you can use plot in views.py?

Answer (score 0):

If your python version is less then 3.3, you need to create an empty file named `__init__.py` into the same directory as plotting.py to make your function importable.

And your plot function must be in function-based view format as demonstrated in django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/views/#a-simple-view

Comment: i am using python 3.8 but running i am running into an unresolved reference when i do `from plotting import plot`. i have made an __init__.py file in the same location but still the reference is not valid. i have also tried `from plotting.py import plot`

Comment: you should import like this `from .plotting import plot`